# java: dialog with 2 button for event "click on Jtable cell"?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a jtable with "data" in my java project:

```
DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTablePolicyView.getModel();
            for(Policy policy : sngltn.GetPerPolicies(cstmr.getPer()))
            {
                model.addRow(new Object[] {String.valueOf(policy.getPolicyId()),...,....});
            }
```

I want that :

1. for **clicking on each cell** in my jtable , **will spring a dialog**(not Form...).
2. will be **two buttons** (with "my label") **on this dialog**.
3. i will be able to **determine what action will happen**(this action *should use the contents of the cell*) **for clicking each button**.

**So what I'm asking?**

1. Is it possible?
2. Example code, greatly help me...

Thank!

---

i try this code for my first mission(for clicking on each cell in my jtable)...
but it's didnt work, why?

**my code:**

```
 public class UpdateCstmrForm extends javax.swing.JFrame 
 {
    ......        
       public UpdateCstmrForm(long person_id) throws Exception 
       {
               DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTablePolicyView.getModel();
                .....
               initComponents();
               .....
                  for(Policy policy : sngltn.GetPerPolicies(cstmr.getPer()))
                  {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]  {......});
                  }                         
               jTablePolicyView.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
               {
                 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
                 {
                   if (e.getClickCount() == 2) 
                   {
                        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                        int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                        int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
                        System.out.println(model.getValueAt(row, column));
                   }
                 }
               }
         ..... 
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Read about [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: ok,i try this code for my first mission(for clicking on each cell in my jtable)... but it's didnt work, why?

`this.jTablePolicyView.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
      JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
      int row = target.getSelectedRow();
      int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
      // do some action if appropriate column
    }
  }
});`

Comment: @user3515151: Edit your question to show new code.

Comment: @trashgod , i added the code to my question

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Okay, I stylize part of the question and the examples again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom editor. The following example should get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/*
 * The editor button that brings up the dialog.
 */
//public class TablePopupEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
public class TablePopupEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor
{
    private PopupDialog popup;
    private String currentText = "";
    private JButton editorComponent;

    public TablePopupEditor()
    {
        super(new JTextField());

        setClickCountToStart(1);

        //  Use a JButton as the editor component

        editorComponent = new JButton();
        editorComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
        editorComponent.setBorderPainted(false);
        editorComponent.setContentAreaFilled( false );

        // Make sure focus goes back to the table when the dialog is closed
        editorComponent.setFocusable( false );

        //  Set up the dialog where we do the actual editing

        popup = new PopupDialog();
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return currentText;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                popup.setText( currentText );
//              popup.setLocationRelativeTo( editorComponent );
                Point p = editorComponent.getLocationOnScreen();
                popup.setLocation(p.x, p.y + editorComponent.getSize().height);
                popup.show();
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });

        currentText = value.toString();
        editorComponent.setText( currentText );
        return editorComponent;
    }

    /*
    *   Simple dialog containing the actual editing component
    */
    class PopupDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener
    {
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public PopupDialog()
        {
            super((Frame)null, "Change Description", true);

            textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            textArea.setLineWrap( true );
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord( true );
            KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
            textArea.getInputMap().put(keyStroke, "none");
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
            getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

            JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancel.addActionListener( this );
            JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
            ok.setPreferredSize( cancel.getPreferredSize() );
            ok.addActionListener( this );

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add( ok );
            buttons.add( cancel );
            getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            pack();

            getRootPane().setDefaultButton( ok );
        }

        public void setText(String text)
        {
            textArea.setText( text );
        }

        /*
        *   Save the changed text before hiding the popup
        */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if ("Ok".equals( e.getActionCommand() ) )
            {
                currentText = textArea.getText();
            }

            textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
            setVisible( false );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Item 1", "Description of Item 1"},
            {"Item 2", "Description of Item 2"},
            {"Item 3", "Description of Item 3"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        // Use the popup editor on the second column

        TablePopupEditor popupEditor = new TablePopupEditor();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor( popupEditor );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Editor Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

It demonstrates how to use a JTextArea as an editor for a cell.